# Xamarin form Navigation page back button not displaying

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, back-button

I need to add a back button to my navigation page. I tried `NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, true);` but it didn't work and I tried in xaml also, still does not work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: In order to have a back button, your page needs to be a `NavigationPage`. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/pages/

Comment: the button will not appear until you have more than one page in your navigation stack

Comment: This is my code,     var page = new ProductDetail();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, true);
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(page));

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't right. In App.xaml.cs you need to set Main page to be new NavigationPage(new ProductDetail());

Then when you navigate **away** from ProductDetail, you will see the back button.

Also normal page navigation will use PushAsync. Are you wanting a modal popup for your second page?

Comment: i have the main page which is tabbed page,App.xaml.cs navigate to my main page, and there i have item listed and once i click on the item i want to navigate to another page which should not be tabbed and has different bar background color and with the back button .

Comment: my App.xaml.cs: Current.MainPage = new TabbedPage { Children = {new NavigationPage(new ItemsPage())
                    {Title = "Discover", },new NavigationPage(new Camera())
                    {Title = "Sell", },new NavigationPage(new Profile()) {Title = "Profile",},}};

Comment: This worked for me as I was starting navigation from my HomePage and was loading HomePage from App.xaml.cs normally. So it was never on the navigation stack.